# Pass function name as argument in mapply?

Tags: r, mapply

I would like to pass a function name as an argument in mapply:

```
f2 <- function(a, b) a + b^2
f <- function(a, b, func) func(a, b)
f(1, 3, f2)  ## returns 10
mapply(f2,  1:2,  3)  ## returns [1] 10 11
mapply(function(a, b) f(a, b, f2), 1:2,  3) ## returns [1] 10 11
mapply(f,  1:2,  3,  f2)  ## fails
```

The final `mapply` call generates the error

`Error in dots[[3L]][[1L]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mapply` assumes you want to iterate over all the vectors you pass after the first function. But you want to use the same value of `f2` for every iteration. You can do that useing the `MoreArgs=` parameter

```
mapply(f,  1:2,  3,  MoreArgs=list(func=f2))
```

You don't have the same problem with the 3 because R will perform vector recycling to expand 3 to `c(3,3)` to match the same length as `c(1,2)`. Functions in R don't have the same implicit recycling behaviors. But if you want the value to always stay the same, it's better to put it in the `MoreArgs` parameter

Comment: Perfect! R obviously knows that f2 is a particular object, namely a function. Where would I look for an explanation of this behavior wrt functions? For example, I can have a list of functions, but I'm not allowed (I understand now) to have a dataframe with a function column.

Comment: It's the difference between where R want's an atomic vector or "primitive" types and places where you can have a more general list. Technically you can kind of have functions in a data.frame but they have to be in "list columns". Like you can do `x <- data.frame(a=1:2); x$b <- list(mean, sum)`. But that would mess up things like `write.table` because you can't write the function to text. Functions are one of the few things that don't behave implicitly like a vector or list without some wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Wrap the function in a list:

```
mapply(f,  1:2,  3,  list(f2))
## [1] 10 11
```

**2)** Typically functions that have function arguments use `match.fun` so that one can pass either the function or a character string containing its name.  For example, `mapply` itself does that so the above line of code could equally be written as: `mapply("f",  1:2,  3,  list(f2))` .  If `f` were written that way then we could simply specify the name of `f2` as a character string, namely `"f2"` .

```
f <- function(a, b, func) {
  func <- match.fun(func)
  func(a, b)
}

mapply(f,  1:2,  3,  "f2")
## [1] 10 11
```